# A Function that returns 0, when the same function executed as a sub returns the correct value

Tags: vba, excel

The below function, when used in a workbook, returns either a 0 value or #VALUE although when executed as a sub returns the correct value. I have tried creating a function that returns the below code as a sub, but I get the same result. My function searches through each sheet in the workbook, finds a table that begins with "Budget*", and adds the cells in a column that is specified by the user. The number of sheets is unknown, so it is impossible to try to write this function as an actual value of a cell. I am stumped!

[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F2kP.jpg) [Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Lbp.jpg)

```
Function IncomeSum(Month)

ColumnNumber = Month.Column
IncomeMonthSum = 0
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In Worksheets
    If WS.Tab.Color = 255 Then Exit For
    If WS.Index >= 4 Then

        For Each Tbl In WS.ListObjects
            If Tbl.Name Like "Budget*" Then
            TableName = Tbl.Name
            Exit For
            End If
        Next Tbl

    ColumnSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(TableName & "[[#All],[Column" & ColumnNumber & "]]"))
    IncomeMonthSum = IncomeMonthSum + ColumnSum
    End If
Next WS

IncomeSum = IncomeMonthSum

End Function
```

Comment: A UDF cannot `Activate` other sheets, for one. Don't work against `ActiveSheet`. Iterate the `Worksheets` collection with `For Each ws In Worksheets`, and then work with `ws` instead of `ActiveSheet`. The `Sheets` collection isn't guaranteed to only contain `Worksheet` objects; `WS` could be anything from a `Chart` to any of half-a-dozen legacy sheet types when you iterate the `Sheets` collection.

Comment: Also `Month` is assumed to be a `Range` object, but the function doesn't declare a type for it, so it will happily take anything a `Variant` can hold (i.e. *literally* anything)., and blow up with a run-time error on `Month.Column` given anything other than a `Range`: declare the parameter `As Range` explicitly to avoid that. Also the function's return value should be `As Long`, or `As Double`, or whatever is appropriate. It's currently returning an implicit `Variant`. Variable `WS` should be declared, too. `Dim ws As Worksheet`.

Comment: You have a logical issue with your code as well: If any of the sheets don't have a table with **Budget** in the name, your last value of **`ColumnSum`** will get added again in **`IncomeMonthSum`**. I would strongly recommend that you use `Option Explicit` option

Comment: Thank you for your input guys! @MathieuGuindon, I made your edit suggestions, but the formula is still giving a value of 0. I don't understand, can a function not perform methods like a sub can? See my updated code to see the edits I made. And Zac, I totally understand, however, with the way I built the workbook, its impossible for a sheet not to have a table named "Budget". I wont bother with the extra code.

Comment: `WS.Activate` is illegal in a UDF. And yes, indeed, a function that is invoked from a cell formula cannot do everything a Sub/macro can. Functions take input, compute a value, output a result - nothing more.

Comment: @Mitch103 unless you're protecting the workbook structure, you can't assume that it's "impossible for a sheet not to have a table named 'Budget'" - a user is 1 click away from breaking your code (i.e. adding even a throw-away worksheet to make on-the-side calculations will break it)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon IT WORKED! IT WORKED! I CANT BELIEVE IT! This has been eluding me for weeks, and it finally works, and cant thank you enough! What a relief! And yes, this will be password protected

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Now I am having another issue. The Cell that this formula is entered in is not updating the value if data is changed in the tables. It only updates when I re-enter the formula into the cell. Any advice?

Comment: Try adding `Application.Volatile` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It worked! You have absolutely made my day! I am on cloud nine right now... my use for UDFs in VBA has increased dramatically, I cant thank you enough!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your function, the primary one being `WS.Activate` and then working against `ActiveSheet`. You have a `WS` worksheet object - *use it*; a UDF is not allowed to `Activate` a worksheet.

Then, you're not declaring the variables you're using. This means you're 1 typo away from breaking everything, and you're not getting all the *IntelliSense* you would get with properly-typed object variables. Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and have a `Dim` statement for every local variable. Doesn't matter where you put the `Dim` statements, they're not executable - my recommendation would be to put them as close as possible to their first assignment.

`TableName` will retain its previous value between `WS` iterations, which means even if `WS` doesn't have a table, your code would try to work with the previous iteration's `TableName`. Reset it between iterations (or better yet, extract a private function that gives you a `ListObject` given a `Worksheet`).

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IncomeSum(ByVal Month As Range) As Double

    Dim ColumnNumber As Long
    ColumnNumber = Month.Column

    Dim WS As Worksheet        
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Tab.Color = 255 Then Exit For
        If WS.Index >= 4 Then
            Dim Tbl As ListObject
            Dim TableName As String
            For Each Tbl In WS.ListObjects
                If Tbl.Name Like "Budget*" Then
                    TableName = Tbl.Name
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next Tbl

            If TableName <> vbNullString Then
                Dim ColumnSum As Double
                ColumnSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(WS.Range(TableName & "[[#All],[Column" & ColumnNumber & "]]"))

                Dim IncomeMonthSum As Double
                IncomeMonthSum = IncomeMonthSum + ColumnSum

                TableName = vbNullString
            End If
        End If
    Next WS

    IncomeSum = IncomeMonthSum

End Function
```

You have a `ListObject` - assuming proper validation of the provided `Month` range, you could use `Tbl.ListColumns(Month.Column).DataBodyRange` instead of hard-coding a table formula.